# how can i bypass close_notify in ssl in firefox?

Tags: tls

i am trying to login to my yahoo mail, but no avail. i recently discovered after monitoring some traffic that the dumb yahoo server doesn't send a close_notify response but just acts ignorantly and closes the ssl session. i know if i do this i may be vulnerable to truncation attacks, but i will disable it as soon as i import everything i have from yahoo and then delete my yahoo account. i want to bypass the close_notify verification in firefox (or iceweasel as you want to call it). thanks.

i'll also quote a comment that has been made in the pidgin support board. it's down here:

> Both GnuTLS and CDSA (Adium's SSL plugin) check whether a TLS
>   connection  has been closed properly by checking if the server sent a
>   `close_notify`  alert first.
>   [https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=508698 NSS  doesn't]. If
>   that alert wasn't sent, GnuTLS and CDSA consider it a fatal  error,
>   which for the HTTPS handler means the response is completely 
>   discarded. That's what's happening here with Yahoo: their HTTPS server
>   closes the connection without sending `close_notify` first.
>
> The danger of not checking for that alert is that any MitM may cause
>   a  response to be truncated, yet we'd be unable to tell that it is.
>
> Is it really an error condition libpurple should consider fatal? I'm
>   not  entirely sure.

Answer (score 1):

To make a SSL implementation not complain about the lack of `close_notify`, the direct method is to download the source code, modify it, then recompile it. This may imply a substantial amount of work. If your OS is some Linux flavour, then the package manager may provide a way to obtain a source tree already configured for proper integration with your system (with `apt-get source` on Debian-like distributions).

Alternatively, you might try to fiddle with `iptables` so as to block the "FIN" flag from Yahoo -- thus emulating an absence of connection closure, which would then explain the lack of `close_notify`; from the point of view of the client, things would remain open. If the HTTP response include a `Content-Length` header, or use chunked transfer encoding, then this as a good chance of working. Notably, the lack of `close_notify` is a security issue only for protocols which rely on connection closure to convey semantic information, e.g. HTTP 0.9, but not "modern" HTTP.

If that's a one shot, you may find it simpler to temporarily use another browser which would be less picky about the `close_notify` when doing HTTP (and that would not be really wrong, as long as the HTTP response are self-terminated). Try chromium.

Comment: can you tell me the iptables command please? i'll assign it to my router so it doesn't complain across all my devices. also using chromium didn't solve the problem.